# Can I append FormGroup to FormData to post multiple inputs having plain text and files?

Tags: angular

1 If I have a signup form as FormGroup which have multiple inputs for plain text as well as files/images. Can I append that form to FormData()? If yes then how can I retrieve fields data because the formData Object I've created posts empty which throws error that "User Request Format is incorrect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps ,also you cant see formdata with console.log you need to do a for-of on the formdata instance to see the values

```js
 uploadFile(event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({
      avatar: file,
    });
    this.form.get('avatar').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
  submitForm() {
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', this.form.get('name').value);
    formData.append('avatar', this.form.get('avatar').value);
    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:4000/api/create-user', formData)
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => console.log(response),
        error: (error) => console.log(error),
      });
  }
```

Comment: I've done the same thing, but when I submit the form it throws the above error. And when I debug this, the formData instance carry nothing which I think leads to the mentioned error.

Comment: formData.get('username'); you can check if the values are inserted like with this ,if values are inserted than maybe you should send json with base64 and not formadata

Comment: I cannot get the point, how do I check the inserted values?  Can I go through with JSON Base64? From where I could find best guide?

Comment: first check carefully what type of data  the backend expects ,you can usualy see this from the accept headers on the response , if it wants json , you can encode a file in base64 and send it with json 
here you have an example how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350670/angular-convert-file-input-to-base64

Comment: The content-type mentioned here in Response Headers is: 'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'. I did not see any accept key. However, in Request headers there is 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*'.

Comment: then i think you shoud try sending it in json format beause it does not look like it supports formdata

Comment: Thanks for your time. Have a good time

Comment: The issue here I find was there was header sending with the URL. I just removed that and it worked.